# Android best practice on how to manage code - in the Activity class or Object class?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, oop

I'm new to Android and am developing my first app. I have arrived at a situation where I have two options but am not sure which would be the best practice and was hoping somebody could clarify this.

As an example, I have a Contact class. Objects of this class are stored in a database which the user can delete from both my MainActivity and from ContactActivity. Would it be best to place this *Delete()* method in both my Activity classes where I can use the context to access the database etc? This would also mean that I would need to create AlertDialogs in each method to ask if the user is sure that they wish to delete (and sometimes more functionality in other scenarios). Or should I create the method inside the Contact class which would require the Context to be passed in as a parameter each time?

This is a single example, I have a number of classes which can all pose the same question.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: dont write duplicate code... I suggest you to write a Dao class that is responsible for SCRUM operations in your app.

Comment: Search for Repository pattern or Data Access Object pattern

Comment: I used content providers so the actual process of deleting the object is handled by one line using getContentResolver().delete(), however in this example I create and display an AlertDialog to double check that the user is sure which can't be done inside the Content Provider class.

Placing this method inside the Contact class and passing the context each time would prevent code being duplicated but is this good OOP practice?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you're developing a mobile project, you need to separate your business logic from your UI logic and the same goes for your model.

This is done to give your mobile application the ability to be mantainable for the long run, because as you incorporate bug fixes or new functionalities, if you have too much code in one class, finding your way in it will be complete chaos.

With that set, I'll propose to you a mobile application arquitecture that might help you:

- UI: Dedicate a package to hold all of your Activities, you can place your Fragments in a separate one. Keep your code free or anything related to database access or modifying your model classes. You want your UI classes free of any code non-related to handling events, presenting UI changes (like changing text, styles, images, loading Fragments, etc). If you need something beyond this scope, then use objects from the other layers I'm about to describe.
- Data Access Objects: Anything related to read from files, accessing an internal database, storing information in either, should go in a different package, these classes should handle any connection to these store places and return the information to be consumed by your UI or other layers.
- Data Transfer Objects: Keep the classes that will represent the information you'll be presenting on your UI free of any complex logic, these classes need to be just POJO to hold information that will be served on the UI or sent across the net.
- Network: If you have to consume web services or connect to remote servers to retrieve any kind of data, you should place the classes for that here.
- Business: Need to retrieve a List of Persons from database using a Data Access Object but filtered by some rule or to handle image processing or some complex operation? Classes like that should be placed here.
- Services: Your services or tasks should be placed in their own package too, avoid declaring them inside your Activities.

If your application need more functionality and you think some of these layers don't work for you, you should add more or remove those you won't be using, in the end the final goal is to keep your project code easy to read and to mantain.

Some might think it's a hassle to have to separate your code into classes, but having a monster class that handles everything will do more harm to you.

Of course, you shouldn't make everything into a class, you can group similar logic into generic type methods and make use of anonymous classes if you have interfaces with only one method.

The end goal is to make your development time and maintainance time less troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

When multiple classes should do the same code, and that code **is** relevant with their using, you should make a [superclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) and inherit from it with the 2 classes.

When multiple classes should do the same code, and that code **is not** relevant with their using (completely different task), you should use a [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) / [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).